# Wrong ldap user and group IDs on nfs

Tags: ldap, nfs, file-permissions, autofs

we have users authentication driven by ldap and home directories shared on nfs server mounted by autofs. We recently installed Ubuntu 15.04 on three new machines and added them to our infrastructure as we always did. One machine was configured by guy #1 and two other by guy #2. Two other have problems :)

The problem is that files ownership is messed up in home directories. All files have an arbitrary owners ids like `4294967294`. We've compared and finally copied all (I believe) important configuration files:

- /etc/ldap.comf
- /etc/idmapd.conf
- /etc/default/nfs-common
- /etc/auto.master
- /etc/auto.home

The two problematic machines also have very long nfs access time in comparison to the third one which is fast as hell. Software versions are the same as we update all these systems constantly.
Any ideas? Maybe some log file that could report problems with ownership resolution?

Comment: duo able yo query ldap server from problematic nodes? Try to clean idmap cache by running 'nfsidmap -c'. Start rpc.idmapd in in a debug mode (rpc.idmapd -f -v) and watch the requests.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was that rpc.idmapd was not started at all. Found two bug reports: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/1428961
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/1449074
Please create an answer and I'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you experience problems with idmapping you need:

- check that client can talk to LDAP/NIS server
- clean idmap cache by running 'nfsidmap -c'
- start rpc.idmapd in in a debug mode
  (rpc.idmapd -f -v) and watch the requests.